# Concurrent Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I completed some basic code to assign 2 threads a task. But I have to make 2 versions where one can have both threads invoke the task concurrently, and one where it would never be concurrent. But I'm not even sure which version I have made, let alone how I would identify it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Week5
{
    static int sharedData = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        atomic myAtomic = new atomic();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(myAtomic);
        thread1.setName("thread 1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(myAtomic);
        thread2.setName("thread 2");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try
        {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "was interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("sharedData = " + sharedData);
        System.out.println("Exiting Main function from: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    public static class atomic implements Runnable
    {
        public synchronized void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Starting 'Atomic' Function from: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        sharedData = sharedData + 1;

            System.out.println("Exiting 'Run' function from: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: It was how to identify if it could be run concurrently or not. I apologize; to make sure the spacing and everything was correct for the site I copy/pasted from another source and left off the last few lines after the code by mistake. That was, of course, where my question was phrased more apparently.

Comment: @Cordre dont explain it here. future readers want to know what your problem is about by reading what you posted. please edit your post

Answer (score 0):

Your threads can never run the same task concurrently, because the `run()` method is synchronized, meaning only one thread can enter at a time for the same object. If it were not synchronized, both threads could potentially execute it simultaneously.

Comment: Perfect. So I just need to remove that single word and they can run simultaneously then?
Also, it is a cruel joke that the teacher required the class to be named Atomic while preventing the use of an atomic int. Threw me off and sent me down the wrong path.

Comment: @Cordre That's right. And the class is doing an atomic update in your case, at least until you remove `synchronized`. Then it would definitely be confusing.

Comment: @Cordre, remove that single word, and they will be _allowed_ to run at the same time, but whether or not they actually _do_ run at the same time is another question.  Your run() method is short.  There's no guarantee that when your main() routine calls thread1.start(), the thread won't run to completion before main() gets a chance to start thread2.